# Is it possible for using Dlib in android like OpenCV?

Tags: android, dll, dlib, .a

Well i need a clear site or information on using Dlib in android. I searched in the net throughout to get a sample application in android using Dlib but still i can't find a one. I am not still sure whether we can use Dlib methods in android for generating .a file so that we can use it as a library. Can anyone suggest me or guide me on how to use Dlib in android and what is its purpose.

Answer (score 4):

This issue has already been dealt [here](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/23). You can refer to https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android for an example. It describes porting dlib to Andriod platform as dynamic or static library with some samples built.