# Face landmark extraction for mobile. Any good open source libraries that will allow to extract facial landmarks with a small file size?

Tags: computer-vision, face-detection

I need to find landmarks of given face image. There are some good libs but I am not sure how big their size in my mobile app since all of them requires training data which have really big file sizes. My priorities are, small file size and landmark detection accuracy, it does not have to be very fast.

Note : Images will be loaded by user so there is no predefined condition. App will detect face and its landmarks.

[image: Example for the reqired quality of landmarks]

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good library for Face landmark detection such as [dlib](http://dlib.net/) and
[dlib' real time face pose detector](http://blog.dlib.net/2014/08/real-time-face-pose-estimation.html) does a good job in ladnmark detection.

Here are some good questions asked about using dlib with android

- https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android
- [Is it possible for using Dlib in android like OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371745/is-it-possible-for-using-dlib-in-android-like-opencv)